# Is it possible to duplicate pytest tests per provider of a fixture?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I have tests that are run on multiple platforms, each represented by a plugin (Python module included in `conftest.py` via `pytest_plugins = [...]`).
Multiple plugins can provide the same fixtures, and I would want each plugin to be responsible for generating its own duplicates of tests during collection.
Example:

```py
# test_something.py
def test_sanity(execution_log):
    assert execution_log
```

```py
# plugins/riscv.py
@pytest.fixture
def execution_log(request, riscv_dependency):
    return riscv_dependency.fetch_log()
```

```py
# plugins/x86_64.py
@pytest.fixture
def execution_log(request, host):
    return host.fetch_log()
```

I would want to sometimes run with and sometimes without RISCV (in this example, to be determined by pytest commandline), and want each plugin to generate its own test variant during collection. I imagine something like:

```py
# Also in plugins/riscv.py
def pytest_collection_hook(item):
    if not item.config.getoption("--riscv"):
        return
    if 'execution_log' in item.fixturenames:
        return pytest.test_from(item, execution_log=riscv_execution_log)
```

And roughly the same thing for the other plugins.

Does something like that exist?

My current best option is to fiddle around with `pytest_collection_modifyitems` to see if I can change which fixtures will be used by the test (looking like the answer is no, but I don't have something better as of yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current solution is:

- For each test (via [pytest_generate_tests](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#std-hook-pytest_generate_tests)):

  - For each enabled modules/plugins:

    - Check if the test should be run with the module's implementation of the
      fixture
    - If so, add the plugin name to a dict
  - Parametrize the test with the fixture providers
  - If no providers were supplied, skip the test
- During test setup, get the actual value using [request.getfixturevalue](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.FixtureRequest.getfixturevalue)

Should look something like this:

```py
# In conftest.py
pytest_plugins = ["plugins.riscv", "plugins.x86_64"]

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def _global_fixture():
    # This is used to skip tests using a mark
    pass

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc: pytest.Metafunc):
    params = dict()
    for module_name in pytest_plugins:
        module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
        for key, provider in module.providers(metafunc).items():
            if key in params:
                params[key] += provider
            else:
                params[key] = provider
    if params:
        metafunc.parametrize(params.keys(), params.values())
    else:
        metafunc.parametrize("_global_fixture", [pytest.param(None, marks=pytest.mark.skip)])  # This skips the test

@pytest.fixture
def execution_log(request, execution_log_provider):
    return request.getfixturevalue(execution_log_provider)
```

```py
# In test_something.py
def test_sanity(execution_log):
    assert execution_log
```

```py
# In plugins/riscv.py
@pytest.fixture
def riscv_execution_log(request, riscv_dependency):
    return riscv_dependency.fetch_log()

def providers(metafunc: pytest.Metafunc):
    if "execution_log" in metafunc.fixturenames:  # Also check that riscv is enabled
        return {"execution_log_provider": "riscv_execution_log"}
```